# How to turn off details being displayed in Media Player Classic?

Tags: windows-10, media-player-classic

[image]

I accidentality pressed some shortcut key and currently not able to turn this details off.

How can this be turned off..?

This is Media Player Classic software running in windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Menu -> View -> Render Settings. Click on Display Statistics.
Or Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

**Note:** You must do either of the steps 3 times to disable it.

Comment: Thank you so much.
Did with Ctrl + J as Render Settings was not available

Answer (score 1):

#### I pressed a shortcut key and currently not able to turn this details off

Your image is showing the basic info of the media file being played.

You should be able to toggle this with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> or `Menu` → `View` → `Information`

Comment: Thank you for your response, finally was able to resolve with Crtl + J